# Discuss the existence and uniqueness of the following operator equation

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing, operator-theory

The question says

**Let $A:X \to Y$ where $X,Y$ are normed spaces.**

$(i)$ **Discuss the uniqueness and existence of a solution of the operator equation $Ax=y$ where $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$ for different operators $A$**

$(ii)$ **Discuss for the different values of $\lambda$ the existence and uniqueness of this operator equation $Ax=\lambda x -y$**

I think for $(i)$  the only way for the solution $x$ to exist is that $A$ becomes bijective in order to have an inverse st $x=A^{-1}y$ and in this case the solution is unique. I don't seem to have any other ideas concerning $(i)$.

for $(ii)$ I think we can never discuss it unless $A:X \to X$. Moreover, I assumed the following about $A$
if $A \in L(X)$ where $L(X)$ is the space of linear bounded operators and $\|A\| \leq \lambda$ then we can re-write the equation as  $(I\lambda - A)x=-y$

where $x= -\frac{1}{\lambda} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{A^n}{\lambda^n}(y)$ this proves the existence and for every choice of $\lambda$ we get a new solution.

I don't have any other ideas.

(**Note. I did not study compact operators **)

Comment: Note that for (i) existence would follow from surjectivity of $A$ and uniqueness from injectivity. Both together follow from bijectivity but it is not necessary for $A$ to have a continuous inverse. For (ii) as you note correctly the expression $\lambda x - y$ needs to make sense. So you need to be able to add vectors of $X$ with vectors of $Y$, which means either $Y$ is a subspace of $X$ or $X$ is a subspace of $Y$. At any rate as you note you are essentially asking the question from before for $(\lambda - A)x=y$, so apply the results from before here.